# How to link developer authenticated user across devices in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm just trying to get a handle over this framework and I want to confirm that my approach is correct.

I can authenticate my own user using the method: `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` and supplying an `IdentityPoolId` and a Logins key-pair with my Developer provider name and a token which I provide.

Now, from what I understand, when the user logs into a second device, in order for Cognito to understand that this is the same user, I have to provide it with an IdentityId. However, I'm not sure of the best way to get the `IdentityId` programmatically so that it will match up with the initial login.

The only technique I can think of is to store the `IdentityId` in my own DB and provide my own method for retrieving it. Is this the best way? Or should I be working with this framework differently?

I'm still a beginner to AWS in general and I'm just trying to understand the best practices for this framework.

BTW, I'm implementing the Android SDK and the PHP SDK for my backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity, it returns the identity id associated with the user identifier you provided.  So if the user identifier you use is the users' username, when you call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with that same username from the second device, it will return the associated identity id.  There is no need to store the identity id unless you want to, it is provided to you each time you call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.

This blog post may be of further help:

http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident

Comment: cool, i see now how it works. whatever i use as my USER_IDENTIFIER in the login key-pair has to be consistent no matter how the user accesses the app using my authentication. i guess i should make another question for this, but is just using something a username or id secure enough for this, or should i generate my own hash or something?

Comment: Since you should be calling getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity from your backend service and signing the request with your developer credentials, using the username should be fine.  You are free to hash the user identifier however.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Cognito, your user first authenticates with an Identity Provider (such as facebook, google or other Oauth provider), and the token you get back from it is sent to Cognito and is the key to tying your users information together across logins on other devices.

You don't need to store this information in a database, unless you are writing you own custom identity provider and not using one of the public ones available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I am writing my own custom identity provider. That's why I'm using the getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity method. With this being the case, the best way is to just store the IdentityId myself? Is that all there is to it?